# Mongoose typescript model creation with multiple connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to create a model while using multiple connections ([following the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections)) but I get the following error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Schema<Document<any>, Model<Document<any>>>' is not assignable to parameter of
type 'Schema<UserInterface, UserModelInterface>'.
Types of property 'methods' are incompatible.
... (a bunch of 'is not assignable - is missing the following properties' errors follow) ...
```

My code looks like this:

<sub>**database.ts**</sub>

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

// const mongo = mongoose.connection(process.env.DB_URI!, {
const mongo = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.DB_URI!, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true
})

export default mongo
```

<sub>**UserModel.ts**</sub>

```js
import mongoose, {Model} from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import database from "../database";

interface UserDocumentInterface extends mongoose.Document {
    firstname: string
    lastname: string
    ...
}
    
interface UserInterface extends UserDocumentInterface {
    // Instance methods
    hashPassword(password: string): Promise<string>
    ...
}
    
export interface UserModelInterface extends Model<UserInterface> {
    // Static methods
    // Currently empty
}

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    ...
})

// Methods definitions
UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = async function(password) {
    return await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
}
...

// const User: UserModelInterface = mongoose.model<UserInterface, UserModelInterface>('User', UserSchema)
const User = database.model<UserInterface, UserModelInterface>('User', UserSchema)
export default User
```

The error appears on `UserSchema`  in `const User = database.model<UserInterface, UserModelInterface>('User', UserSchema)`

What I don't understand is why this line works without issues

```js
const User: UserModelInterface = mongoose.model<UserInterface, UserModelInterface>('User', UserSchema)
```

but this one throws an error

```js
const User = database.model<UserInterface, UserModelInterface>('User', UserSchema)
```

when the only thing that changes is the connection type, `mongoose.createConnection()` as opposed to mongoose default connection

Comment: I don't really know about the issue above. But to share my experience, I tried to use Mongoose with types in a big project and it really was a hassle. It never really worked correctly. Also using underlying MongoDB was not a good decision (at least for our data structure). I recently switched to Prisma with PGSQL and the TypeScript developer experience is way above what I will ever get with Mongoose and NoSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that as of version `mongoose 5.11.11` there are some conflicts with `@types/mongoose` that break class inheritance when using typescript ([see this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9790)).
I also found the solution to my problem in [this discussion](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9801), it revolves around moving the Document and Model interface from the model to the schema constructor.

In practice it means turning this

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    ...
})
    
const User = database.model<UserInterface, UserModelInterface>('User', UserSchema)
export default User
```

into this

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema<UserInterface, UserModelInterface>({
    firstname: {                            // INTERFACES GO HERE 
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    ...
})
                // INSTEAD OF HERE
const User = database.model('User', UserSchema)
export default User
```

To me this looks like a temporary fix, **the issue will probably affect only v5.11.11** as it's being patched in 5.11.12 so I suggest visiting the links above to see the issue status before using this suggestion.